# How to get value from response of axios get in react

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, webapi

I am trying to get values from a table to show in my dropdown list in react however when I console.log my dropdown value I am getting [object][object] as my return. How do I get the values from my table to show in the return. This is my code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getLocations();
  };

  getLocations = data => {
    console.log('Hello');
    var Items = [];
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:44303/api/observation/';
    axios.get('https://localhost:44303/api/observation/GetLocations').then(response => {
      response.data.map(item => {
        Items = item;
        this.setState({ locations: Items });
        //this.setState({ locations: response.data });
      });
      console.log('DDL:' + this.state.locations);
    });
  };
```

locations is a state variable how do I get my response to show value of the table

Comment: You should log object `console.log('DDL:',  this.state.locations);` , so that you can see `locations` value in console

Comment: Try this: 
`console.log('DDL:',  JSON.stringify(this.state.locations))`